# capistrano set up for ruby sinatra app in new ubuntu server

Tags: ruby, sinatra, capistrano

I have a ruby sinatra app which needs to be deployed.
I am trying to set up capistrano for deployment to a new ubuntu server. 
So when i get a fresh ubuntu server, how should I proceed with setting up capistrano.

I see that in the blogs, initially the unicorn and nginx are installed manually.

Should I ssh into that ubuntu machine and manually install ruby, rubygems , unicorn and nginx and set up rbenv in that machine  and then set up capistrano from my local machine.??
Or is there any better way to approach.??

Answer (score 0):

I'm using capistrano only with ruby on rails, so I can't offer any advice on sinatra specific issues. But the basic setup should be similar.

At first you should install ruby, nginx, git and the basic tool chain to install (and compile) the most common gems:

```
apt-get install --no-install-recommends ruby ruby-dev gcc g++ libc6-dev zlib1g-dev git nginx
```

Depending on the database you're going to use, you'll need the relevant headers too. If you plan to use postgres, you'll need to install the following packages:

```
apt-get install --no-install-recommends postgresql libpq-dev
```

The only gem you need to install by hand is bundler:

```
gem install bundler
```

At least with ruby on rails all other gems will be installed by capistrano automatically (through the Gemfile).
Then you're supposed to setup a deploy user as suggested by the [capistrano documentation](http://capistranorb.com/documentation/getting-started/authentication-and-authorisation/) and configure your sinatra application accordingly.

Comment: So the things I need to install are bundler  ruby nginx, unicorn and ruby gems and  rbenv set up by hand manually doing ssh into ubuntu?? I dont require git and any database since my app is not using any db

Comment: Yes. But as far as I know capistrano requires a version control system such as git.

Comment: yes..  we will be installing git in my local machine only.. not in the ubuntu server where i want to deploy the code right??

Comment: I'm afraid you'll need a public accessible git repository. But since you have a server you can host your repository there.